# Bearded dragon thinks I'm food

Tags: behavior, reptiles, bearded-dragon

I just got a bearded dragon (he's still just a baby), he's eaten plenty and he's a healthy boy, but the problem I have is that he thinks my fingers are food!

He has no problem with my boyfriend petting him, but as soon as I put my hand in the cage he thinks I'm food and runs for my hand :( I just tried to place my hand in his vivarium with a bit of vegetable on my hand, he went no where near the vegetable and bit my finger thinking it was food! And as he thinks I'm food he won't let me pet him I need some advise please.

He doesn't puff up or get angry he just goes to bite me

I put his food in his vivarium from a tub, and sometimes feed him a worm off my hand, but he follows my hand when I open his cage or he will come for my hand if I just place it in his vivarium.

Is he biting me because he thinks my hand is food, and how can I get him to stop?

Answer (score 0):

What do your fingers look like? The rare time that I give my uromastyx "super-worms", he acts like he's on crack for like 10 minutes after and will go after anything moving that could be remotely mistaken for a worm. If you have long narrow fingers, and you give him insects, he may be confused.

What you can try is giving him the back of your hand to "bite". It isn't possible for him to actually bite the back of your hand, so he'll repeatedly tongue it. I'm guessing he'll eventually realize that you're not food.

Comment: Yes they are long and narrow and I will try giving him the back of my hand and see how he takes it thank you